# How to delete a row from a typed dataset and save it to a database?

Tags: .net, database, sql-server-2008-r2, ado.net, dataset

I am doing this as a small project to learn about disconnected and connected models in .NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have three tables:

```
Companies (PK CompanyID) 
Addresses (PK AddressID, FK CompanyID) 
ContactPersons (PK ContactPersonID, FK CompanyID)
```

CompanyID is assigned manually by the users. The other IDs are auto-generated. Companies has a one-to-many relationship with ContactPerson. I have set any changes to cascade.

I display all records in Companies in a DataGridView and when a row is clicked, the corresponding records in ContactPersons are displayed in a second DataGridView.

I have successfully implemented updating and inserting new records but I completely fail in my attempts to delete rows and save the changes to the database.

I us a typed dataset.

If I use this:

```
DataRow[] contactPersonRows = m_SoldaCompaniesFileDataSet.ContactPersons.Select("ContactPersonID = "
                                                  + this.m_CurrentContactPerson.ContactPersonID);

m_SoldaCompaniesFileDataSet.ContactPersons.Rows.Remove(contactPersonRows[0]);
```

The records are displayed properly in the DataGridView but are not saved in the database later.

If I use this:

```
DataRow row = m_SoldaCompaniesFileDataSet.ContactPersons.Rows.Find(this.m_CurrentContactPerson.ContactPersonID);
row.Delete();
```

The records are set but I get an exeception: DeletedRowInaccessibleException, when I try to refresh the DataGridView. The exception pop-s up in the auto-generated dataset.design file.

I am pretty much stuck at this point since yesterday. I cannot find anything anywhere that remotely resembles my problem. And I cannot understand actually what is going on.

Comment: use m_SoldaCompaniesFileDataSet.AcceptChanges() after Delete().

Comment: Thanks for your answer! According to the documentation:

Remove() is like calling Delete() and then AcceptChanges();

I have tried that already before and it doesn't work.

I have tried all kinds of combinations. And I have an DeleteCommand set in the Designer like that:
    DELETE FROM ContactPersons
    WHERE        (ContactPersonID = @Original_ContactPersonID)

Comment: Remove only removes the record from collection where Delete permanently delete data from database also when AcceptChnages is called.

Comment: So do you have any idea why I get DeletedRowInaccessibleException when I try to refresh/repopulate the DataGridView after I have used Delete() on the DataSet.

Comment: let me know one thing, are you calling Acceptchanges() after deleting row (not remove) now. if not then try.

Comment: Yes, I am! If I call AcceptChanges() I do not get the DeletedRow... exception but the deletion does not get saved to the database on the server. It gets saved if I do not apply AcceptChanages() (in that case I am immediately closing the form, which forces dataadapter.Update()) but then I get the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing Linq-to-Data set query like this:

```
var dataRows_ContactPersons = from row in this.m_SoldaCompaniesFileDataSet.ContactPersons
                              where row.CompanyID == companyID
                              select new
                              {
                                   ContactPersonID = row.ContactPersonID,
                                   CompanyID = row.CompanyID,
                                   NameFirst = row.NameFirst,
                                   NameLast = row.NameLast,
                                   PhoneNumber = row.PhoneNumber,
                                   EmailAddress = row.EmailAddress,
                                   Position = row.Position
                              };
```

It took me quite some time to figure out that I need to exclude the deleted rows from the Linq query by doing this check:

```
row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted
```

So the above code is fixed like that:

```
var dataRows_ContactPersons = from row in this.m_SoldaCompaniesFileDataSet.ContactPersons
                              where row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted && row.CompanyID == companyID
                              select new
                              {
                                   ContactPersonID = row.ContactPersonID,
                                   CompanyID = row.CompanyID,
                                   NameFirst = row.NameFirst,
                                   NameLast = row.NameLast,
                                   PhoneNumber = row.PhoneNumber,
                                   EmailAddress = row.EmailAddress,
                                   Position = row.Position
                              };
```

No more DeletedRowInaccessibleException :) Please note, that the check if a row is in a deleted state must be performed everywhere in the code.